# Problems deploying Qt application using QtWebkit and OpenSSL on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, qt, openssl, qtwebkit

I have an application that I'm writing that uses QtWebkit and OpenSSL which deploys fine on Mac OS X 10.6 or higher and Windows XP SP2 or higher, but I'm having problems deploying the application on Linux (Unix) platforms. I've made a tarball of the application including a bin and lib folder and set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH to the local lib folder and included all Qt and external libraries on the lib folder. When my application tries to load webpages using SSL, it can't resolve the functions necessary for SSL. I've gotten deployment to work if I install the development libraries for OpenSSL on my target machine, but I'd like to have my application use the release libraries for OpenSSL on the user's machine. Am I missing something in my pro file?

Here's the relevant code from my pro file:

```
QT += core gui webkit network sql xml

unix:LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../usr/local/lib/ -lqjson

unix:INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../usr/local/include
unix:DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../usr/local/include

macx:LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../../usr/local/lib/ -lqjson

macx:INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../../usr/local/include
macx:DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../../usr/local/include

win32:LIBS += -L C:/qjson/lib/ -llibqjson

win32:INCLUDEPATH += C:/qjson/include
win32:DEPENDPATH += C:/qjson/include
```

I'm considering making a deb and rpm package to resolve dependency problems, but I'd rather not make several packages for each available Linux distribution. This is why I went the tarball method first. I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you didn't compile Qt with support for SSL. Read about it [here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/ssl.html)

Comment: Can I compile the QtNetwork and QtWebkit modules linking against open-ssl without having to compile the entire Qt framework from source? It takes quite a while to compile Qt from source.

Comment: You should compile all of the components from source with the same configuration- otherwise you will likely run into deployment issues.